# Extract string with 3 place left and 2 places right of the match in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a data of tyres that is usually shown with a `/` to give the width and thickness as follows.

```
c("120/70 R19 Pirelli Scorpion Rally STR", "120/70 ZR 19 Pirelli Scorpion Trail II", 
"120/70 ZR17 Pirelli Diablo Rosso III", "120/70 ZR17 Pirelli Diablo Rosso Corsa II", 
"Pirelli MT 60 RS 120/80 ZR18", "120/70 R17 V", "160/70TR17 73V Dunlop&#174; Harley-Davidson Series, radial, GT503", 
"120/70R19 60V", "MT90B16 72H", "120/70ZR-19 60W", "150/80-16,71H,BW", 
"100/80 R17", "130/70B18 63H BW", "100/90B19 57H", "100/80 R17", 
"100/90B19,57H,BW", "100/90B19 57H", "100/90B19,57H,BW", "130/90 B16 73H", 
"120/70R19 M/C", "110/90B19,62H,BW", "BW 130/80B17 65H", "120/70ZR-19 60W", 
"160/60R18,70V,BW", "130/90B16,53H,BW", "130/80B17 65H", "120/70 -R18", 
"110/70-17 M/C 54S", "120/70 ZR17", "120/70ZR17", "100/90-19M/C 57S", 
"120/70ZR17M/C (58W)", "120/70ZR17M/C (58W)", "120/70 ZR17", 
"110/80R19 M/C (59V), tubeless", "120/70-17", "120/70ZR17M/C (58W), tubeless", 
"120/70ZR17M/C (58W), tubeless", "120/70-ZR17", "110/80 x 19", 
"120/70 ZR17", "120/70 ZR17", "130/90-16M/C 67H, tube type", 
"120/70ZR18M/C (59W), tubeless", "130/90 B16", "100/90-19", "120/70 - R17", 
"130/90-16", "100/90-R18", "100/90-18", "150/80 R17 V", "90/90-21", 
"120/70 ZR17", "100/90-19 Metzeler Tourance", "100/90-18")
```

Now I want only the thickness `/` and width for example `120/70` out of a clutter of other text details for each tyre. I am not getting a suitable expression to do that.

Somehow the following line does the trick but there are two `NAs`, see

```
str_extract(g3$`Front Tyre:`, '\\d{3}/\\d{2}')
```

Comment: `sub('.*(\\d{3}/\\d{2})\\D.*|.*', '\\1', x)`

Comment: thanks, but it gives the same output with blank space instead of NAs. It needs to handle either 3 or 2 elements of left-hand side.

Comment: You could change the empty to NA, also you t handle 3,2, just do `\\d{2,3}`